# Computing a system of ordinary differential equations with initial condictions over a continuous range

Tags: numerical-integration, difference-equations

I have some questions about Mathematica programming and would appreciate if you could help me.

I want to solve a system of ordinary differential equations `μ '[t]` and 
`λ'[t]` and each equation contains a large number of terms so it is impractical to write them explicitly. I express these terms as two functions `F1` and `F2` that depend on two parameters `P1` and `P2` and `λ[t]` and `μ[t]`.

I have been able to solve this system for a couple of initial conditions `λ[0] = ic1` and `μ[0] = ic2`, but I would like to solve my system of equations for a continuum of values `​​λ[0] = {0, ..., Pi/2}` and `μ[0] = {0, ..., Infinity}` and then get `λ[t]` and `μ[t]` and use them to perform an integral on `λ = λ[0] = {0, ..., Pi/2}` and `μ = μ[0] = {0, ..., Infinity}` that are precisely our initial conditions.

I integrate the product of a function `G` in the time `t` (where `λ[t]` and `μ[t]` are taken into account for a certain initial condition defined by the continuous ranges of the integral) with the same function, but in `t = 0` (where the initial conditions are taken into account with the continuous ranges of the integral).

The structure of the program is:

```
ode = 
 {μ'[t] == F1[p1, p2, λ[t], μ[t]], 
  λ'[t] == F2[p1, p2, λ[t], μ[t]], 
  μ[0] == {0, ..., Pi/2}, λ[0] == {0, ..., Infinity}};

Sol = NDSolve[ode, {μ, λ}, {t, 0, 1},`Method -> "Some method to choose"]

μ1[t_] := Evaluate[μ[t] /. Sol] // First
λ1[t_] := Evaluate[λ[t] /. Sol] // First

data = 
  ParallelTable[
    {t, 
     NIntegrate[ 
       G[p1, p2, 
         μ1[t] "for the initial condition μ = μ[0]", 
         λ1[t] "for the initial condition λ=λ[0]"] 
       G[p1, p2, 
         μ "= μ[0]", λ "= λ[0]"] , 
         {μ "=`μ[0](initial condition)", 0, Pi/2}, 
         {λ "= λ[0](initial condition)", 0, Infinity}, 
       Method -> {"Some method to choose"}]}, 
       {t, 0, 1}];`
```

Comment: try [ParametricNDSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html) and [ParametricNDSolveValue](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue.html)?

Comment: Ok, but the parameters have values: p1 = 15, p2 = 10.

Comment: Please provide a minimal **working** example.